# retrofit/RxJava Scheduler

Tags: multithreading, retrofit2, rx-java2, scheduler

I have the bellow code line that run a network call to retrieve a token :

> `service.token(initAuth()).blockingGet()`

while token function have the following definition : `func token : Single<Token>`

Theoretically, the call need to be done into the main thread because a created **retofit** with `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()` which by definition run all request in the *mainThread* hence my call to refresh/get the token need to trigger a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` whish is not the case. It seem that these behavior is due to the call to `blockingGet` but the documentation doesn't state that a particular thread is used.

> **blockingGet** does not operate by default on a particular *Scheduler*

Which push me to ask how the call is done in another thread then the `mainThread`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in my sample app I have 2 networks call *one* to retrieve **cars** and the other for retrieving the **token**. Somehow Retrofit store the scheduler used for **cars** call and use it for the **token** call.

The definition of **cars** call :

> ```
> .cars()
> .subscribeOn(schedulerProvider.io())
> ```